# Reset ASP.NET Form After PostBack?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have asp.net web form for comment product. I want to reset html value, after postback.

```
        Sad.Ajax.Post({
                    "handler": "Comment",
                    "data": formItems,
                    "ok": function (result) {
                        if (!result.Ok) {
                            Sad.Modal.Alerts.Error(result.Msg);
                        } else {
                            Sad.Modal.Alerts.Success(result.Msg);
                            container.find('input[type"text"],select,textarea').each(function () {
                                var o = $(this);
                                if (o.is("select")) {
                                    o.val("0");
                                } else {
                                    o.val("");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I have asp.net web form for comment product. I want to reset html value, after postback.

Comment: Assuming you have a `form` variable somewhere, just call `form.reset()`.

Comment: Or use the PRG pattern: after the *P*ost, *R*edirect to the same page, using a *G*et to get a fresh form

Comment: i add form.reset() but it doesnt work.

Comment: reset doesn't "empty" the form, but sets it to its initial state - which may be half-filled

Comment: where is the post back button? an ajax.post is in fact used to PREVENT AND NOT HAVE AND NOT REQUIRE a post back. So, you have what looks to be a ajax call, and the whole idea of a ajax.post is TO PREVENT and NOT HAVE a page post-back. However, if you actually do and did mean you have a post-back on that page, then why not re-set with code behind then?